# Error 1004 "Application-defined or Object-defined error"

Tags: excel, vba

I have a piece of code that triggers sometime VBA Error 1004 "Application-defined or Object-defined error". The code is:

```
ToleranzString = "=COUNTA(R[-1]C[3]:R[-1]C[3])"
```

The whole piece of code is:

```
 With myArea
            With .Worksheet.Range(.Cells(1, COLIDX_MESSUNG_1), .Cells(1, COLIDX_MESSUNG_1 + noOfVal - 1))
                If .NumberFormat <> Parameter.NumberFormat Then .NumberFormat = Parameter.NumberFormat
            End With

            If .Cells.Item(2, 4) <> 0 Or noOfVal > 0 Then
                ToleranzString = "=COUNTA(R[-1]C[3]:R[-1]C[" & VBA.Format$(POS_TR_DATEN + Me.Datenbereich.Columns.Count) & "])"
            Else
                ToleranzString = "=COUNTA(R[-1]C[3]:R[-1]C[3])"
            End If
           .Cells.Item(2, PosFormelSub1).Formula = ToleranzString
```

where myArea is an Excel.Range object.

The error is raised after 2nd evaluation of a sheet full of data. Can anyone give an advice on how to debug such an issue or what can be the root cause.

Comment: I don't see how that line can error as you are only assigning a string to a (presumably) string variable. What do you mean by "The error is raised after 2nd evaluation"?

Comment: You use `"=COUNTA(R[-1]C[3]:R[-1]C[3])"`in a cell, as for a variable you can't use referenced formulas, what is the reference? You need to use this instead: `ToleranzString = Application.CountA(YourRange)`

Comment: @SJR this error apears on a specific locations not in all sites, when using the same database. I have't been able to reproduce the error on my machine only on the user machine. On the user machine the user appears sometimes after 2nd evaluation but not always.

Comment: @Damian : I'm not using reference type in a cell, whay u say that I'm using reference types.  .Cells.Item(2, PosFormelSub1).Formula = ToleranzString

Comment: I think there's stuff you're not telling us. Btw it should be `FormulaR1C1` as you are using RC notation.

Comment: Why don't you just use the formula and avoid the use of `ToleranzString`? there is no need to keep formulas in strings.

Comment: Are you absolutely sure that `VBA.Format$(POS_TR_DATEN + Me.Datenbereich.Columns.Count)` will always return valid column index? Same for `COLIDX_MESSUNG_1 + noOfVal - 1`

Comment: @buran until now the index was corret. When do you say that the index will not be valid; an example will be welcomed :-)

Comment: @SocketM, e.g. could it become 0? We don't know what values of POS_TR_DATEN and Me.Datenbereich.Columns.Count are/could be

Comment: I'm kind of confused. What type of object is `MyArea` ? Because at start of your code, with that `With MyArea` is like you were saying later on `With MyArea.Worksheet.Range(.Cells(1, COLIDX_MESSUNG_1), .Cells(1, COLIDX_MESSUNG_1 + noOfVal - 1))` so I guess `MyArea` is a `Workbook` object, and collection `Worksheets` needs an index/name, so line should be `With MyArea.Worksheets(whateveryourindexis).Range(.Cells(1, COLIDX_MESSUNG_1), .Cells(1, COLIDX_MESSUNG_1 + noOfVal - 1))`. So as I said at start, I'm kind of confused.

Comment: @FoxfireAndBurnsAndBurns, `Worksheet` is a property of `Range` class too, returning the parent `Worksheet` of the range object it's being called upon. (i.e. it's like the `Parent` property). Hence a statement like `myArea.Worksheet.Range(…)`, with `myArea` being a `Range` object, is perfectly valid

Comment: Thanks for your comment, @DisplayName I knew about `Parent` but not about `Worksheet` as a property of range class. Learned something new today. Thanks again!